# MongoDB returning null for querying all documents in .NET

Tags: c#, mongodb

Im writing an application using MongoDB, and when I query it from my C# code, I get `null`. There is data in my database [image: data]
My code is

```cs
public async Task<List<Item>> GetItems() =>
    await _items.Find(Builders<Item>.Filter.Empty).ToListAsync();
```

My ASP.NET application, which I use to manage the data, works perfectly fine, but doesn't use Async methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have fixed itself after waiting some time. I have no clue why this happened. If anyone does, please tell me so it doesn't happen again.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. Then I realized that my class properties were not properly mapped. Pretty much case-sensitivity matters.

Here is the link to the MongoDB documentation on how to map classes:
https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/reference/bson/mapping/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31770358)